# System.requestVersion() doesn't give me the patch. How can I get it programmatically?

Tags: apex, managed-package, versioning

The Version class has methods to get the major, minor, and patch version numbers, but after getting the version using System.requestVersion(), patch() seems to always return *null*. Is there a way in Apex to get the patch number without going through all the hassle of the metadata API?

Comment: And you're doing this from within your managed package code?

Comment: @sfdcfox That's right.

Comment: That's odd. Time to dig out my old fake managed project...

Comment: Its documented to behave that way by design apparently. Seems pretty odd to me. If you ever found a solution I'd be interested to hear it.

`The value returned by the System.requestVersion method is an instance of this class with a two-part version number containing a major and a minor number. Since the System.requestVersion method doesn’t return a patch number, the patch number in the returned Version object is null.`